# php Same date hours avoid how to write in php

Tags: php

Get mssql query out put

```
Date        id  training_hours assesments_hours
10-02-2020  18  NULL          NULL
11-02-2020  18  8             NULL
12-02-2020  18  8             NULL
13-02-2020  18  NULL           4
10-02-2020  18  NULL          NULL
11-02-2020  18  8             NULL
12-02-2020  18  8             NULL
13-02-2020  18  NULL           4
10-02-2020  18  NULL          NULL
03-02-2020  18  NULL          NULL
```

### But I want Result is
Month    |id  | Totalhours

feb-2020 | 18  | 20

Note: Same date hours avoid how to write in php

Comment: you can use group by month from the date. Provide your query here, I'll try to update your query.

Comment: Is total hours the sum of training_hours and assessment_hours? What if one or both are NULL? Can you change the query or only make changes in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($Subcount as $element)
{

```
if (($date = ($element->schedule_date)) and ($trainer_id=($element->trainer_id)) and is_numeric($element->training_hours) and is_numeric($element->assesments_hours) and is_numeric($element->training_or_assesment_hours) ) 

{

    $totalsByDate[$date] += $element->training_hours;
    $totalsByDate[$date] += $element->assesments_hours;
    $totalsByDate[$date] += $element->training_or_assesment_hours;
    
}
```

}
foreach ($totalsByDate as $date => $total ) {

```
$result[$firstid.'|'.$tutor_name.'|'.$employmenttype.'|'.$month_year.'|'.substr($date,0,7)] += $total;
```

}